# Clarification on python terminology

Tags: python, terminology

I've written a piece of code:

```
def Greeting():
    return "Hello there!"
Greeting.help = "This function will say hello"

print(Greeting())
print(Greeting.help)
```

What I am unsure what the Greeting.help would be called... I've tried searching but i feel like i'm using the wrong search terms.

Comment: Property? But why do something like this?

Comment: In python, functions are first order objects. Search up what that means, and then you’ll realize these are simply “member variables” or “properties”

Comment: don't use capital case for function names

Comment: Actually the proper python terminoloy is "attribute" (python's "property" is a computed attribute, and "members variables" is C++/Java terminology).

Comment: @IvanVinogradov while it does indeed violate pep08, it's technically legal to capitalize a function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set an *attribute* on the object `Greeting`. That's why the corresponding functions are called `getattr` and `setattr`.

```
>>> getattr(Greeting, 'help')
'This function will say hello'
>>> setattr(Greeting, 'foo', 'bar')
```

These attributes are stored within the dictionary `Greeting.__dict__`, which can also be accessed by `vars(Greeting)`.

```
>>> Greeting.__dict__
{'foo': 'bar', 'help': 'This function will say hello'}
>>> vars(Greeting)
{'foo': 'bar', 'help': 'This function will say hello'}
```

Note that the idiomatic way to set a help/docstring goes as follows:

```
>>> def foo():
...     'help text'
...     pass
...
>>> foo.__doc__
'help text'
```

Answer (score 2):

You've set a single attribute of an object (a function object in this case).

If you wanted to document it, then a more traditional way is to set the docstring:

```
def Greeting():
    """ This function will say hello """
    return "Hello there!"
```

then it can be viewed via `help(Greeting)`:

```
>>> def Greeting():
...     """ This function will say hello """
...     return "Hello there!"
...
>>> Greeting.__doc__
' This function will say hello '
>>> help(Greeting)
```

It prints:

```
Help on function Greeting in module __main__:

Greeting()
    This function will say hello
(END)
```

Comment: s/property/attribute/. In Python a property is this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property